# Wordexp behavour with &

Tags: c, posix, expansion

Does anybody knows `wordexp()` behaviour with strings, which contained `'|'` or `'&'`.

I use `wordexp(str, &res, WRDE_UNDEF)`, but with all strings, which contained `'|'` or `'&'` `wordexp()` returns `WRDE_BADCHAR`. I want that `wordexp()` doesn't report this.

E.g. I want that `wordexp("a & b", &res, WRDE_UNDEF)` returns `wordexp_t` with 3 strings `"a" "&" "b"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illegal characters (`newline` or `|`, `&`, `;`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`) need to be escaped. This is done by prefixing them with `\`.

Verbatim from [`man wordexp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html):

> **The string argument**
>
> Since the expansion is the same as the expansion by the shell (see sh(1)) of the parameters to a command, the string s must not contain characters that would be illegal in shell command parameters.  In particular, there must
>          not be any unescaped newline or |, &, ;, <, >, (, ), {, } characters outside a command substitution or parameter substitution context.